# Loop through or access array of Strings

Tags: arrays, string, vbscript

I am trying to access the values of Session.Contents, some of which appear to be String Arrays.

I've tried to retrieve the values in these arrays using the code below and also directly:

```
Session.Contents.Item(sessItem)(1)
```

Both ways throw an error.  Based on [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035513/how-can-i-convert-a-string-array-to-a-variant-array-in-vbscript) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383823/how-to-access-string-type-in-vbscript), it seems like this just isn't possible in VBScript?

Line 92 corresponds to

```
For each x in Session.Contents.Item(sessItem)
```

I got the loop from [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525093(v=vs.90).aspx), but the example code didn't dim objArray which worked well.

```
Dim sessItem,x
For Each sessItem In Session.Contents 
If IsArray(Session.Contents.Item(sessItem)) Then 
    Response.Write("Type of sessItem contents = " & TypeName(Session.Contents(sessItem)) & "  VarType = " & VarType(Session.Contents(sessItem)) &"<br>")
    Response.write sessItem & " : an array of the following " & UBound(Session.Contents.Item(sessItem))+1 & " items <BR>" 
    For each x in Session.Contents.Item(sessItem) 
        Response.write "- " & x & "<BR>" 
    Next 
    ElseIf IsObject(Session.Contents.Item(sessItem)) Then 
        Response.write(sessItem & " : Session object cannot be displayed." & "<BR>") 
    Else 
        'Response.write(sessItem & " : " & CStr(Session.Contents.Item(sessItem)) & "<BR>") 
    End If 
Next
```

Type of `sessItem` contents is `String()` (VarType = 8200).

Cached_AccountDetails : an array of the following 11 items

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
>   Type mismatch
>   Statement.asp, line 92

Comment: I’ve had this before many times if you are trying to scrap the session for information you will come up against automation types that just aren’t supported in VBScript and 8200 is one of them.

Comment: Relevant [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30511987/692942).

Comment: To qualify an array you need to check that `VarType()` is equal to `8204` *(`vbArray + vbVariant`)* as this is the only supported array type in VBScript. That way anything else can be filtered and ignored.

Comment: @Lankymart So my initial assumption is correct and I can't access the values of VarType 8200 using VBScript?

Comment: That is correct as detailed in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check for Null values as well, also there needs to be better handling for `Nothing` and for nested/mixed-type arrays, and finally there needs to be output escaping via `Server.HtmlEncode()`, in order to get values with HTML special characters displayed properly.

It's worthwhile to write a recursive utility function that can dump any kind of value (except arrays of any other type than `Variant`, as VBScript cannot deal with them):

```vb
Sub Dump(value)
    Dim isCollection, i
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each i In value
        isCollection = (Err.Number = 0) And Not IsArray(value)
        Exit For
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    If isCollection Then
        Response.Write "<i>Collection</i><br>"
        For Each i In value
            Response.Write "<b>" & Server.HtmlEncode(i) & "</b> : "
            Dump value(i)
            Response.Write "<br>"
        Next
    ElseIf IsArray(value) Then
        Response.Write "<i>" & Replace(TypeName(value), "()", "(" & (UBound(value) + 1) & ")") & "</i><br>"
        If TypeName(value) = "Variant()" Then
            For i = LBound(value) To UBound(value)
                Response.Write i & ": " 
                Dump value(i)
                Response.Write "<br>"
            Next
        Else
            Response.Write "(cannot display non-variant arrays)"
        End If
    Else
        Response.Write "<i>" & TypeName(value) & "</i> "
        If IsObject(value) Then
            If Not value Is Nothing Then Response.Write "(cannot be displayed)"
        ElseIf Not IsNull(value) Then
            Response.Write Server.HtmlEncode(value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Usage is simple:

```vb
Dump Session.Contents
```

Output for a variety of things I've tested it with:

> *Collection*
> **FOO** : *String* BLA
> **BAR** :
>   *Boolean* True
> **BAZ** : *Integer* 42
> **QUX** :
>   *Variant(4)*
> 0: *Integer* 1
> 1: *Integer* 2
> 2:
>   *Double* 3,14159265
> 3: *Date* 17.12.2018
>   19:22:15
> **WALDO** : *Null* 
> **FRED** :
>   *FileSystemObject* (cannot be displayed)
> **QUUX** :
>   *Nothing*

Missing: Nested output for nested arrays. Could be done using `<ul>`/`<li>`.

Comment: I'm assuming the last line continuation character was a typo?  I get an expected end of statement error with it included.  If I take it out, I still get the same Type Mismatch error on the For Each x in item line.

Comment: Yep, that was a typo. I've taken it out already. Let me double-check the code.

Comment: @GrendelKhan I could not reproduce that error, but I've updated the code anyway to catch a couple more conditions.

Comment: I think you get the `TypeMismatch` error in that `For Each x ...` loop because `x` can *again* be a either primitive value (printable) or an Array/Object/Nothing/Null (not printable), and the code did not check for that. The updated code does a better job.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this.  I like the generality of your utility, but I still get an error when it reaches the String array.  In your last comment, you said an Array is not printable?  When I call `Dump Session.Contents`, I get:  _IVariantDictionary_ (cannot be displayed)

When I loop over the keys and call `Dump Session.Contents(key)`, I get:

_String(11)_
0:

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: 'value'

This happens on the line `Dump value(i)` in the IsArray loop.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the answer? I've made a few small amendments over time, the `IVariantDictionary` should not show up at all. But I am still stumped at the error you see. A String array should have a string at position 0, I have no idea why it does not seem to be that way for you.

Comment: @Tomalak no amount of checking will help because VBScript cannot handle true string arrays, just check whether the array is `VarType()` `8204` and move on.

Comment: That's the missing part right there. I knew you could not create them, I didn't know you could not even iterate them. I'll amend the code to react to variant arrays only.

Comment: @Tomalak the key is it can’t create them because every type in VBScript is a subtype of `Variant`, it has no way to create a true typed array.